# dictionary not accepting a tuple that has a HuffmanTree in it

Tags: python

I am trying to use a tuple that contains a single element, a HuffmanTree, as a key in a dictionary, but the error I am getting says that HuffmanTree is unhashable. Why is it doing that when I have placed it in a tuple and am using the tuple as a key?

huffman is a HuffmanTree I have already built

#I made it a tuple

```
huff_tup = (huffman,)
```

#and am trying to make it a key in a dictionary

```
freq_dict[huff_tup] = huffman.number
```

Comment: because a `tuple` with unhashable elements is unhashable

Comment: The tuple is asked for its hash value and in turn asks its items for their hash values to combine them to a hash value of the whole tuple.